# Adding JButtons Outside the JFrame Constructor

Tags: java, jframe, jbutton, actionlistener

I am making a card game for class that requires a dealButton to deal out a hand of cards and display them in the frame. I have a loop that goes through the given hand and creates and displays the cards properly, but when that code is moved from the constructor and into the dealButton's ActionListener, nothing displays.

Is there a way to add JButtons to the frame outside the constructor?

Here is the code that should be displaying the hands:

deck.shuffle();

```
        Hand hands[] = deck.deal(4, 13);

        GridBagConstraints handCon1 = new GridBagConstraints();
        handCon1.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
        handCon1.gridy = 10;

        int handSize = hands[0].getCards().length;
        Card cards[] = hands[0].getCards();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < handSize ; i++){
           JButton card = new JButton();
           PlayCardListener playCard = new PlayCardListener(deck, cards[i], card);
           card.addActionListener(playCard);
           card.setIcon(new ImageIcon(cards[i].getImg()));
           card.setBorder(null);
           handCon1.gridx = i;
           add(hand1);
           hand1.add(card, handCon1);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. You only say "when I try it outside constructor it doesn't work". Then **post** that code that is not working. And the answer to your question is: YES, that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

It sure is possible:

```
public class Deal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Deal();
    }

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField statusField;
    private JButton dealButton;
    private JPanel buttonsPanel;

    private Deal() {
        statusField = new JTextField("starting - press DEAL");
        statusField.setEditable(false);

        dealButton = new JButton("DEAL");
        dealButton.addActionListener(this::doDeal);

        buttonsPanel = new JPanel();

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(dealButton, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(statusField, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.setSize(600, 200);
        frame.validate();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void doDeal(ActionEvent ev) {
        buttonsPanel.removeAll();
        List<String> cards = Arrays.asList("A", "2", "3", "4", "5");
        Collections.shuffle(cards);
        for (String text : cards) {
            JButton button = new JButton(text);
            button.addActionListener(this::doCard);
            button.setActionCommand(text);
            buttonsPanel.add(button);
        }
        statusField.setText("new buttons");
        frame.validate();
    }

    private void doCard(ActionEvent ev) {
        String text = ev.getActionCommand();
        statusField.setText(text);  // just demo
    }
}
```

I suspect the following segment of your code:

```
for (...) {
    ...
   add(hand1);
   hand1.add(card, handCon1);
```

check if it is really needed to add `hand1` in the loop (multiple times) - but just a guess without knowing what it is.

Some points to consider:

- Swing components (JPanel, JButton, ...) should only be changed on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) - this is the case for code executed in the ActionListener
- after layout related changes the `validate` method should be called to (re-)layout the component

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I actually resolved the issue by simply adding hand1.validate() and hand1.repaint() at the end of the loop. Now it is working exactly as intended!